# How to get a Gem bag in multiplayer BG:EE with a full party?

Tags: baldurs-gate-enhanced

In Baldur's Gate: Enhanced Edition, a recruitable NPC named Neera possesses the only "Gem Bag" in the game. I am playing a game with a friend of mine, each of us controlling 3 characters. We would really like this gem bag.

In single player, getting Neera to join your party is how you can get the bag. Then you can dismiss her and regain a previous NPC companion. However, in multiplayer, it doesn't seem possible to recruit a custom character you've dismissed previously -- attempting to talk to them yields no conversation. Thus, if we dismiss one of our characters, we cannot get him/her back.

How can I regain a custom party member in BG:EE multiplayer such that I can effectively steal Neera's gem bag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was missing something. Whether this is by design or by mistake, you have exactly one chance to re-recruit a dismissed custom party member into your party. That chance is immediately after you dismiss them. So to get Neera's gem bag, or any NPC equipment that you'd like:

- Go to the location containing the NPC with the gear you want.
- Move one of your party members far away from the others but on the same screen.
- Recruit the NPC, dismissing your far away party member.
- Pause the game.
- Move the desired gear onto nearby party members from the NPC.
- Unpause and allow your recently dismissed character to reach your party.
- Readmit that character and dismiss the NPC.

If you select "No" to avoid re-admitting the party member, you cannot get them back via normal means.